# save method in django object not saving boolean model field it it is passed false

Tags: python, django, request, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField("Comentário")
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Criação")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Última modificação")
    confidential = models.BooleanField("Confidencial", default=False)
```

and I have this viewset (using rest framework):

```
    @detail_route(methods=['POST'], permission_classes= [IsOwnerOrReadOnly])
    def set_confidential(self, request, pk=None):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if(request.data.get("booleanField", None) != None):
            comment.confidential = request.data["booleanField"];
            comment.save()
            return Response({'from':'set_confidential','status':_("Confidential status changed")})
        else:
            return Response({"status":status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
```

The problem is that when I pass "False" value to that view my object is updated but the field "confidential" remains True (assuming that it was like that before). Why does this happen?

Comment: Now I realized that the value of request.data["booleanField"] when converted to bool ( 'bool(request.data["booleanField"]' ) always return True even if booleanField value is **"false"**. How python convert string to bool?

Comment: The doc for the built-in function **bool** in python says this:

_Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class 
 bool.
The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be 
 subclassed._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save the `comment` object.  And note that any non-empty string is considered `True` in boolean context:

```
comment.confidential = (request.data["booleanField"].lower() == 'true')
comment.save()
```

Comment: Thanks @catavaran. I had put comment.save() before. I accidentally erased when I post here.
Still using comment.save(), comment.confidential does not change if the value in booleanField comes False.